# Best way to compare dates in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assume the following table...

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy_Data 
(
    ID INT, 
    TextField VARCHAR(20), 
    DateField DATE
)

INSERT INTO Dummy_Data (ID, TextField, DateField)
VALUES (1, 'Random Text', '2018-01-04'),
       (1, 'Random Text', '2018-02-04'),
       (1, 'Random Text', '2018-05-01'),
       (2, 'Random Text', '2017-01-14'),
       (2, 'Random Text', '2017-05-01'),
       (2, 'Random Text', '2018-01-01'),
       (2, 'Random Text', '2018-02-01'),
       (3, 'Random Text', '2018-01-04')
```

I would like to return the `MAX(DateField)` for each `ID` if the DATEDIFF is less than 90 days between each row.

If the DATEDIFF is greater than 90 days between each row I would like to return the `MAX(DateField)` for each grouping per say.

Example:

So taking rows 1 to 3 from the above we know that the DATEDIFF in days between each row is less than 90 so I would only want to return:

```
ID   TextField      DateField
-------------------------------
1 -  Random Text    2018-05-01
```

However: rows 4 to 7 have an occurrence where the DATEDIFF is greater than 90 days so I would want to return:

```
ID   TextField     DateField
-------------------------------
2    Random Text   2017-01-14
2    Random Text   2017-05-01
2    Random Text   2018-02-01
```

Thank you to anyone that can resolve this predicament.

Comment: I don't understand the rules you're using to produce your expected result. Rows 4-7 have _two_ gaps of 90 days or more: 2017-01-14 precedes 2017-05-01 by more than 90 days, and 2017-05-01 precedes 2018-01-01 by more than 90 days. This gives you three groups of dates among those records whose `ID = 2`. So why don't you expect three records in the result set? Also, why do you expect 2018-05-04 for `ID = 1` when there is no record in your sample table that has that date?

Comment: Hi Joe, great spot. I have amended my question to reflect that comment.

Comment: One more question: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: in a common table expression use the LEAD() analytic to look ahead each row partitioned by ID ordered by DateField ASC) and determine if difference is > 90 days, or if next date is null, then X that record in a new column.  now that you have that result in a CTE, return only the X records.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: In that case @xQbert's approach is exactly what I was going to suggest!

Comment: @Floyd  thx for the DDL, sample data and a good example to illustrate the problem. This provided the MCVE (Minimally Complete Verifiable Example)  most are looking for in a good question. The only thing better would have been to show sample logic (SQL) of what you tried.and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RexTester DEMO](http://rextester.com/EQKXR75365)  (using express 2014)  hopefully works in 2012..

Lead(), CTE, and DateDiff are supported, so I can't think why it wouldn't...

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID
       , textField
       , DateField
       , case when datediff(dd,datefield, lead(datefield) over (partition by ID order by DateField ASC)) > 90 
                OR lead(datefield) over (partition by ID order by DateField ASC) is null then 1 
         else 0 end bInclude
  FROM  Dummy_Data)

SELECT ID, textFIeld, DateField, binclude
FROM CTE
WHERE bInclude = 1;
```

we use LEAD() to look ahead at the next datefield for an ID.  If null or if > 90 days we mark that record with a 1; otherwise it's a 0 then we only include the 1's.

Giving us:

```
+----+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+
|    | ID |  textFIeld  |      DateField      | binclude |
+----+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 |  1 | Random Text | 01.05.2018 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  2 |  2 | Random Text | 14.01.2017 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  3 |  2 | Random Text | 01.05.2017 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  4 |  2 | Random Text | 01.02.2018 00:00:00 |        1 |
|  5 |  3 | Random Text | 04.01.2018 00:00:00 |        1 |
+----+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hopefully you're cleaning this up as the original isn't valid syntax, but it's the right idea. A minor suggestion: it might be easier to understand if the CTE simply produced an integer field `Gap` having the result of the `datediff` with no `coalesce` required, and if the outer query looked for records `where Gap is null or Gap > 90`.

Comment: Updated.  w/ working demo  Had to get rid of the = for the 90 day's

Comment: @xQbert CTE is not an area I've looked at but your comment followed a similar logic to what I was thinking possibly with LINQ.

This has however produced exactly what I needed so I will adapt it for purpose. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Floyd  FYI: CTE = Common Table Expression.  They basically allow you to generate a temporary dataset in memory and reference it like a derived table; but with more flexibility. It lets you do crazy things like recursion in SQL; or reference a CTE table multiple times using one query.  Pretty neat stuff really.  This same approach could have been accomplished using a derived table as well; but I find the CTE "Steps" based approach cleaner and easier to follow the top down method.

Comment: @JoeFarrell  Thanks for the input: I took the or approach instead of the coalese.  I always wonder about the performance and which would be faster though; performance vs readability/maintainability I struggle with those two concepts from time to time.  I generally consider OR's expensive. SO I have a habit of avoiding them w/o really checking the performance anymore.